# youtube-v3-api caption insertion / upload. Is this a bug, or user error?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

If you are here,  could you please help.

I am writing regarding what I believe to be a bug in the YouTube API.  This bug is specifically related to uploading Captions.  A few months ago my code was working just fine but now I am getting confusing and conflicting results. The code completes successfully without errors, I get a successful response resource to my API request, but the caption never shows up in the video.

Example:

When I insert a caption into my video via the API, I get the returned request resource parameters as shown below:

```
caption.ETag = S8i_ANyv6PJCc-Gt8GCDtMmwhDs

caption.Id = AJeb0wHwXDQbYbfxMnqekEmpi6KuVS3zIRaJ6Cbk2VAoG4QIglaPYQjhS3oAAGU7

caption.Kind = youtube#caption

caption.Snippet.AudioTrackType = unknown

caption.Snippet.LastUpdated = 2021-04-14T17:47:25.124086Z

caption.Snippet.Name = qkColN99heU_Caption

caption.Snippet.Status = syncing

caption.Snippet.TrackKind = standard

caption.Snippet.VideoId = qkColN99heU
```

As you can see, it all appears to be correct.  A caption ID is given and the status says syncing.  I also have a status event that triggers when the caption insert is successfully completed so I know it completes successfully without errors.

However, the caption never shows up in my video.  Am I doing something wrong?  Can you verify the above caption.ID is assigned to the video.ID  **qkColN99heU**?  Everything I see is telling me that the procedure was successful, but it is still not shown in my test video that I uploaded.

Some additional info.

The caption file is a plain text  (.txt file), and in the caption request I have Sync set to true.  I understand that there is a delay for the Google AI engine to sync the plain text to the video, but even after several hours, the caption still has yet to appear in the video.

Here is the code that is executed after the video is uploaded that should insert the caption.

```
Caption caption = new Caption();

if (NewVideoID != null)
{
    //create a CaptionSnippet object...
    CaptionSnippet capSnippet = new CaptionSnippet();
    capSnippet.Language = "en";
    capSnippet.Name = NewVideoID + "_Caption";
    capSnippet.VideoId = NewVideoID;
    capSnippet.IsDraft = false;

    //set the completed snippet to the object now...
    caption.Snippet = capSnippet;

    //..Here we read and upload / insert our .txt file which contains our subtitles/captions...
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(CaptionFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var captionRequest = youtubeService.Captions.Insert(caption, "snippet", fileStream, "application/atom+xml");
        **captionRequest.Sync = true;**
        captionRequest.ProgressChanged += CaptionInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        captionRequest.ResponseReceived += **CaptionInsertRequest_ResponseReceived**;

        //finally upload the request... and wait.
        await captionRequest.UploadAsync();
    }
}
```

On the  `CaptionInsertRequest_ResponseReceived` event handler shown in the code above, I get the following:

**Bytes Sent 156 bytes** (The exact size of the .txt caption file that was uploaded)

**Exception: null**  (No exceptions raised)

**Status: Completed** (Confirmation that the caption insert was completed successfully)

Also, in the Google API console I can see the API metrics for the queries and quotas etc. for both my video uploads and caption insertions.  So it appears i am hitting the API correctly otherwise i would not see the quota deductions etc (I am assuming).

My channel id is **UCjUBOpA3OZDDhdZsRvIw8pg**

The video id is  **qkColN99heU**

The caption id is  **AJeb0wHwXDQbYbfxMnqekEmpi6KuVS3zIRaJ6Cbk2VAoG4QIglaPYQjhS3oAAGU7**

The caption Etag reference id is **S8i_ANyv6PJCc-Gt8GCDtMmwhDs**

Could you please help me understand why the captions are not appearing in my videos?  I have tried multiple times.  Everything seems to be working perfectly apart from the caption actually displaying in the video.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to try filing a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/